# c#, which coding technique is faster?

Tags: c#, silverlight-3.0

```
public static Dictionary<string,List<LookupItem>> dict;

if (dict == null)
{
   dict = IsolatedStorage.GetDropDowns();
   return dict["Priority"]
}
else
   return dict["Priority"];
```

**or**

```
try
{
   return dict["Priority"];
}
catch(KeyNotFoundException e)
{
   dict = IsolatedStorage.GetDropDowns();
   return dict["Priority"];
}
```

This is a silverlight application, i have dropdowns cached in isolated storage (if i had to query the wcf service for every lookup then the datagrid takes forever to appear, im well aware that dropdowns could become outdated and i have a means of updating the dictionary when new values are added/removed via a callback), in my xaml, i have a converter that converts the Id returned from a dbquery to the related LookupItem object. I know im never supposed to use try's and catch's as part of application logic, but i realy need the fastest possible approach therefore im willing to ignore that architectural no-no. The reason the dictionary would become null is since im storing the dictionary as a static var in an arbitary class, if the user had to hit F5 to refresh the page, the dictionary would lose its values since the xap file is reloaded and my caching page that executes on login would not execute."Priority" contains a of List. LookupItem contains Key/Value that is needed for ComboBoxes and so on.

1) Is a dictionary the most effecient way of storing this information?
2) which of the two approaches will yield the fastest possible return of the List?

Comment: Your two examples are not equivalent, so it's moot to discuss which is faster. Also, both could in principle throw `KeyNotFoundException`s and `NullReferenceException`s.

Comment: Test it... right a little app that repeats the same operation thousands of times and use a StopWatch to compare.

Comment: Also, the first example needs curly braces or you'll get a compile error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the fact that your first example is lacking some braces, it'll be much faster, because an if-expression is executed in virtually no time, whereas throwing an exception, creating the necessary handlers and traversing the stack frame is somewhat more work for the CLR...

So if you're calling the 'dict' field less than say 500.000 times, it's clearly #1. Regarding your first question: I'm not totally sure, because I'm not a WPF-hero, but usually there's rarely something more efficient than a Dictionary for this kind of data.

And btw.: You wouldn't get a 'KeyNotFoundException' in the above case, but a 'NullReferenceException'...

Comment: Thanks, i actually wrote the example from memory and made a mistake, it was supposed to be NullReference, i was thinking about 2 different problems at the same time, which in my case, both were solved in a single thread.

Answer (score 8):

Well you're lacking braces to start with, but I'd write it as:

```
if (dict == null)
{
   dict = IsolatedStorage.GetDropDowns();
}
return dict["Priority"];
```

Note that you'll probably need some locking to make this thread-safe. In fact, why not just write it as:

```
public static Dictionary<string,List<LookupItem>> dict 
    = IsolatedStorage.GetDropDowns();
```

to start with? Then you know it'll never be null.

Anyway, please don't use the second idea. The check for nullity is insanely fast, and anyway you'll still fail with a `NullReferenceException` rather than a `KeyNotFoundException`...

If you really want to behave differently depending on whether or not a key is present, you should use (assuming `dict` is already non-null):

```
List<LookupItem> list;
if (!dict.TryGetValue("Priority", out list))
{
    // Deal with the key being missing
}
else
{
    return list;
}
```

I would also question your judgement about needing this to be "the fastest possible approach" - once you've made sure that you only perform the fetch from WCF once, are you sure it's *really* a performance bottleneck? I'd be shocked if that were the case.

Comment: This could potentially be called 10 000 times in a single datagrid, since it exists to bind an Id to a dropdown key/value pair for multiple columns of a grid

Answer (score 1):

1. A dictionary seems like a
   reasonable approach to storing the
   data.
2. Your two code samples are testing different things. For ensuring `dict` is non-null, see Jon's answer.

The best alternative to try/catch(KeyNotFoundException) is TryGetValue:

```
List<LookupItem> priority = null;
if(!dict.TryGetValue("Priority", out priority))
    throw new ApplicationException("Could not find Priority list.");

return priority;
```